# remove space between 2 div in HTML5

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have problem removing spaces between the Div's. My html has a DIV-container1 IMG-image DIV-container2 and I want all the 3 things to be aligned without any spaces in between. Kindly see the fiddle and provide me with a solution. 
Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gjWFn/)
`

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
            <title>gamehistorylotto</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login_screen.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/common/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/date.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/common/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
            </head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" style="background: url(images/bkg.png) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover">
        <div data-role="header" id="titleHeader" data-position="fixed">

            <img src="images/b_retour_on_euro.png"  onclick="history.go(-1); return true;" class="ui-btn-left">

                <h1>MES JEUX ET GAINS</h1>

                <img src="images/logout_euro_off.png" class="ui-btn-right">
                    </div>
        <div id="totalAmtSection" >
            <label id="connectLbl">Connecte</label>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
           <div id="container1">
                <label data-role="none" id="date">Date : </label>
                <label data-role="none" id="hour">Heure : </label><br>
                <label data-role="none" id="serialno">Serial No : </label><br>
                <label data-role="none" id="receiptno">Receipt No : </label><br>
                <label data-role="none" id="game">Game : </label><br>
                <label data-role="none" id="price">Price : </label><br>
                <label data-role="none" id="subscription">Subscription : </label><br>
                <label data-role="none" id="draws">Draws : </label>
            </div>
              <img src="images/overlay_divider_horizontal.png" id="splitter" />
            <div id="container2">
                <label data-role="none" id="whiteboxlbl">Played numbers:</label><br><br>
                <div id="whiteboxcontainer">
                    <center><label data-role="none" id="ltnumber"></label>
                    <label data-role="none" id="super6">Super 6 : </label><br>
                    <label data-role="none" id="spiel77">Spiel 77 : </label><br>
                    <label data-role="none" id="superzahl">Superzahl : </label><br></center>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

        <style type="text/css">

            #splitter{
                height:7px;
                margin:0;
                width:100%;
                display:inline;
            }
            #whiteboxlbl{
                font-size:16px;
                color:white;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            #date{
                font-size:16px;
                color:white;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            #hour{
                font-size:16px;
                margin-left:5%;
                color:white;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            #serialno{
                left:15%;
                font-size:16px;
                color:white;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            #receiptno{
                font-size:16px;
                color:white;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            #game{
                font-size:16px;
                color:white;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            #price{
                font-size:16px;
                color:white;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            #subscription{
                font-size:16px;
                color:white;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            #draws{
                font-size:16px;
                color:white;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-weight:bold;
            }

            #container1{

                display:block;
                margin-top:10%;
                padding-right:5%;
                padding-left:5%;
                padding-bottom:5%;
                padding-top:5%;
                background: transparent -moz-linear-gradient(
                top,
                #37b6d2 0%,
                #4398bf);
                background: transparent -webkit-gradient(
                linear, left top, left bottom,
                from(#37b6d2),
                to(#4398bf));
                -moz-border-radius: 4px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
                border-radius: 4px;
                border: 1px solid #55b2be;
            }
            #container2{
                display:block;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                padding-right:5%;
                padding-left:5%;
                padding-bottom:5%;
                padding-top:5%;
                background: transparent -moz-linear-gradient(
                top,
                #37b6d2 0%,
                #4398bf);
                background: transparent -webkit-gradient(
                linear, left top, left bottom,
                from(#37b6d2),
                to(#4398bf));
                -moz-border-radius: 4px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
                border-radius: 4px;
                border: 1px solid #55b2be;
            }
            #whiteboxcontainer{
                top:0;
                padding-top:5%;
                padding-bottom:5%;
                height:100%;
                width:100%;
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(
                top,
                #ffffff 0%,
                #ffffff 25%,
                #ffffff 50%,
                #ffffff 90%,
                #dadce8);
                background: -webkit-gradient(
                linear, left top, left bottom,
                from(#ffffff),
                color-stop(0.25, #ffffff),
                color-stop(0.50, #ffffff),
                color-stop(0.90, #ffffff),
                to(#dadce8));
                -moz-border-radius: 4px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
                border-radius: 4px;
                border: 1px solid #000000;
                -moz-box-shadow:
                0px 3px 11px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
                inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
                -webkit-box-shadow:
                0px 3px 11px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
                inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
                box-shadow:
                0px 3px 11px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
                inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
                text-shadow:
                0px -1px 0px rgba(000,000,000,0.2),
                0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
            }
            #totalAmtSection
            {
                height:25px;
                width:100%;
                top:37px;
                position:absolute;
                padding:0px !important;
                margin:0px !important;
                color:white;
                font-size:11px;
                background:url('images/bg_loggedin_1px.png') repeat;
            }
            #connectLbl
            {
                float:left;margin-left:1%;padding:6px;
            }
            #portLbl
            {
                float:right;margin-right:1%;padding:6px;
            }
            .ui-btn-left {
                height: 80%;
                margin:5%;
                float: left;
            }
            .ui-btn-right {
                height: 80%;
                margin:5%;
                float: right;
            }


        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">


            var historyArray=["316-54568709-02316","31000016","13,15","1","Saturday"];
            function dynamichistory(){
                var content;
                var arraynumber;
            for(j=0;j<historyArray.length;j++)
            {
                content=historyArray[j];
                arraynumber=j;

                if(arraynumber==0)
                {
                    $("#serialno").append(content);
                }
                else if(arraynumber==1)
                {
                 $("#receiptno").append(content);   
                }
                else if (arraynumber==2)
                {
                    $("#price").append(content+'€');
                }
                else if (arraynumber==3)
                {
                    $("#subscription").append(content+' week(s)');
                }
                else

                {
                    $("#draws").append(content);
                }

            }
            }
                dynamichistory();


            var date=new Date();
            var ftdate=(date.getDate()  + '/' + (date.getMonth()+ 1) + '/' +  date.getFullYear());
            $("#date").append(ftdate);
            var hour=new Date().toTimeString().replace(/.*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*/, "$1");
            $("#hour").append(hour);
            a=12;
            var numberArray = ["11","12","13","22","07","45"];
            for(i=1; i<=a; i++){
                function dynamicrows(){
                    var content = '<table>'
                    content='<center>'
                    content += '<tr><td>';

                    for(j=0;j<numberArray.length;j++)
                    {
                        content += numberArray[j] ;
                        if(j!=(numberArray.length-1))
                        {
                            content+='-'
                        }
                        content += '</label>'
                    }

                    content += '</td></tr>'
                    content += '</center>'
                    content += '</table>'

                    $("#ltnumber").append(content);

                }
                dynamicrows();
            }
            var superArray = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"];
            var superFlag="yes";
            superNumber=1;
            for(i=1; i==superNumber; i++){
                function superdynamic(){
                    var content='<label id="superNumber" class="inline superNumber" >';
                    if(superFlag=="yes")
                    {
                    for(j=0;j<superArray.length;j++)
                    {
                        content += superArray[j] ;
                        content += '</label>'
                    }
                    $("#super6").append(content+ ' : OUI');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for(j=0;j<superArray.length;j++)
                        {
                            content += superArray[j] ;
                            content += '</label>'
                        }
                        $("#super6").append(content+ ' : NON');
                    }
                }
                superdynamic();
            }
            var spielArray = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"];
            var spielFlag="no";
            spielNumber=1;
            for(i=1; i==spielNumber; i++){
                function spieldynamic(){
                    var content='<label id="spielNumber" class="inline spielNumber" >';
                    if(spielFlag=="yes")
                    {
                    for(j=0;j<spielArray.length;j++)
                    {
                        content += spielArray[j] ;
                        content += '</label>'
                    }
                    $("#spiel77").append(content+ ' : OUI');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for(j=0;j<spielArray.length;j++)
                        {
                            content += spielArray[j] ;
                            content += '</label>'
                        }
                        $("#spiel77").append(content+ ' : NON');
                    }

                }
                spieldynamic();
            }

            var superzahlNumber=["3"];
            function superzahldynamic(){
                var content='<label id="superzahlNumber" class="inline superzahlNumber" >';

                for(i=0; i<superzahlNumber.length; i++)
                {
                    content += superzahlNumber[i] ;
                    content += '</label>'
                }
                $("#superzahl").append(content);
            }
            superzahldynamic();

            var total=["100.5"]
            function totaldynamic(){
                var content='<label id="totalamount" class="inline totalamount" >';

                for(i=0; i<total.length; i++)
                {
                    content += total[i] + '€';
                    content += '</label>'
                }
                $("#total").append(content);
            }
            totaldynamic();

            var portfolieAmount = "100.50€";
            var portLbl = $("<label>", {id: "portLbl"}).text("Portefeuille : " + portfolieAmount);
            $("#totalAmtSection").append(portLbl);
        </script>
    </div>

</body>
```

`

Comment: It's easier for folks to help you if you post a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/ that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh He posted a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gjWFn/

Comment: _Kindly pay me to work for you_...

Comment: The point of a fiddle is to simplify your problem, recreate the issue with *the least code as possible* and simple elements so we don't have to dig through 100s lines of your code

Comment: Simplified fiddle. CLICK [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2wByQ/)

Comment: I would suggest to use a `*{margin:0;padding:0}` style-reset code on top of your css, to avoid such problems in the future.

Comment: Though we are not seeing the gap in the fiddle, I am seeing it in the browser(chrome).. I am using jquery, if that is causing the problem, how should we correct?

Comment: @DarkAshelin I tried this, it doesn;t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `<p>` element that is causing space between your two `<div>` elements.  Change like so:

```
<p style="margin: 0;"><img src="images/overlay_divider_horizontal.png" id="splitter"></p>
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/gjWFn/1/

Comment: *Inline styles are evil*

Comment: @DarkAshelin You are evil!  Just kidding; I just used the inline as an example.  Proper solution would be not to change all `p` elements as you suggest, but to create separate `class` for this element.

Comment: I am seeing the gap still. There should not be ANY gap between the 3.

Comment: @user2706195 change the `line-height` of the `p` to `0px` too. (or just remove the `<p>` really)

Comment: @user2706195 See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gjWFn/2/ It will produce a gap the same size of your spacer image.  If you don't want any gap, then just remove the element all together...

Comment: @user2706195 I added a new class `.spacerP` and I removed the `height` attribute of your `#splitter` class.  Accept answers that answer your question and upvote answers and comments that helped you.

Comment: @user1477388 I am seeing it in the fiddle, but not in the browser. I am using jquery, if that is causing the problem, how should i resolve.

Comment: @user1477388 your solution only worked in the fiddle. I accessed the html after the suggested changes, but it didn't work.

Comment: @user2706195 If it works on fiddle then it works...  jsfiddle is a real environment.  If it doesn't work for you, then your issue is elsewhere and you need to make sure your code matches mine.

Comment: @user1477388 That's correct. I will check mine. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wb4GU/) in the fiddle the seperator in between Date and played numbers is padded 5% on the left and 5% on the right. How can we make it 100% for the container?

Comment: @user2706195 comments are getting too long.  Open a new question for your last comment and accept an answer here which answers the question you initially asked.

Comment: @user1477388 can you please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18638556/separator-not-occupying-100-in-html5

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `margin` and `line-height`of your `p` tag:

```
p{
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

To be honest I don't know why you are using a `p` tag there. Just remove it and put your `img` by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can :

- reset margin/padding of div with CSS
- add a commentary between 2 lines in the HTML code like