# Separator not occupying 100% in HTML5

Tags: jquery, css, html

Separator is not occupying 100% area of the container. There should not be any space on the rightand left to the separator between date and played numbers. Any solution for this please?[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wb4GU/)

```
           `<div id="container1">
                <label data-role="none" id="date">Date : </label>
              <img src="images/overlay_divider_horizontal.png" id="splitter" />
                <label data-role="none" id="whiteboxlbl">Played numbers:</label><br><br>
            </div>
             #splitter{
                height:7px;
                margin:0;
                width:100%;
                display:inline;
            }
            #whiteboxlbl{
                font-size:16px;
                color:white;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            #date{
                font-size:16px;
                color:white;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            #container1{
                display:block;
                margin-top:10%;
                padding-right:5%;
                padding-left:5%;
                padding-bottom:5%;
                padding-top:5%;
                background: transparent -moz-linear-gradient(
                top,
                #37b6d2 0%,
                #4398bf);
                background: transparent -webkit-gradient(
                linear, left top, left bottom,
                from(#37b6d2),
                to(#4398bf));
                -moz-border-radius: 4px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
                border-radius: 4px;
                border: 1px solid #55b2be;
            }`
```

Comment: This is not clear at all. Please clarify

Comment: Your div.container1's padding-left, and padding-right of 5% is preventing it from stretching all the way.

Comment: this way? http://jsfiddle.net/wb4GU/2/

Comment: I have a image between the label date and Played numbers:.I have left/right padded the container1 with 5%. Image is just a line dividing the labels and it should occupy 100% width of the container. At present you could see a gap on the left and right side. The divider should touch the container ends.

Comment: @Devin I know that and I am here for a solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent containers padding is set to 5% so the child element can only expand as much as the padding will allow.

To resolve this in your example I suggest you remove the left and right padding from the parent and set margins on the child elements you do not want to be 100% width.

e.g.

```
#container1 {
   padding-top: 5%;
   padding-bottom: 5%;
   padding-left: 0%;
   padding-right: 0%;
}

#container1 label {
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/wb4GU/6/

---

Another potential solution is to expand the splitter to have a width greater than 100% and then shift it across the page as necessary

```
#splitter {
    width:110%;
    margin-left: -5%;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/wb4GU/5/

Answer (score 0):

It's because the splitter is in the container div and the container has padding right and left.

Remove from #container1:

```
padding-left: 5%;
padding-right: 5%;
```

Alternatively, if you want the 'Date:' and 'Played Numbers' in the same position, change the width in #splitter to:

```
width: 110%;
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/wb4GU/2/

```
width:110%;
margin-left: -5%;
```

This should work